# Creating custom MIME contents in emails

Tags: email, marketing-cloud

I would like to include a new MIME section in a triggered send email in addition to the HTML and text ones.

I want to include ICS data in my emails and would like to do it as a part in a MIME email.

Is this possible to do in ExactTarget today and if so how should I construct the email template and trigger?

Edit: Note that I am aware of the possibility of adding the ICS file as an attachment but that is not an option due to both cost and potential deliverability issues. What I really want is a multipart email with a section that is the ICS file with a Content Type of text/calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Any attachment such as an ICS file would need to be included in the email by using the AttachFile() AMPscript function:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/

Comment: I just realized that ICS is not one of the supported attachment extensions so the solution I proposed will not work.  Sorry for the confusion.